# Set id from sql database to jsp <input type="submit">

Tags: java, html, sql, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to set up dynamically id of button in JSP. I'am able to get all information from database, show them as the list on my page. I want to delete user from button, but I dont know how to retrieve information which user should be deleted. So I created something like this to set up user id to button id. How should I do this? I have something like this

```
<% if(request.getAttribute("users")!=null) { %>
                <% 
                        ArrayList<User> users=(ArrayList<User>) request.getAttribute("users");
                %>
                <% for (User object: users) { %>
                    <div class="element">
                        <%=object.getEmail()%> &nbsp
                        <%=object.getFirstName()%> &nbsp
                        <input type="submit" value="Edit">
                        <input type="submit" id="<%=object.getId()%>" value="Remove">
                    </div>
                <% } %>
            <% } %>
```

Its not working at all. Where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: try to use c taglib for jsp ... it is much better

Comment: can I set it in my way?

Comment: And you can use simpler notation like `${object.email}` if your User is a correctly formated bean ;)

Comment: You just need a input button and add a listener on click (pure javascript here). the listener function will retrieve the id and then call the correct webservice.